# How to run an arbitrary startup function in a ring project?

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I've got a compojure/ring application I currently run with `lein ring server` that I'd like to compile to a .war so I can deploy it. I've got a definition, however, just like

```
 (def foo (start-scheduler))
```

That blocks the compilation and the generation of the .war. To circumvent this, I thought about moving the call to a startup function, but how would I call it when the server launches?

If I put the call inside the handler, I'd end up with the same problem as before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your `project.clj` when declaring your Ring handler you can also specify an init (and destroy) function that is run when your application starts:

```
:ring {:init myproject.core/init
       :destroy myproject.core/destroy
       :handler myproject.core/handler}
```

This is documented here: https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring#general-options